# How to select children without an id

Tags: javascript, dom

I need get 2 elements inside a DIV, but this element don`t have a unique identifiers, what is the appropriate selector method?

```js
const buttonElem = document
  .getElementById(wrapper)
  .element.getElementsByTagName("button");
const inputElem = document
  .getElementById(wrapper)
  .element.getElementsByTagName("input");

buttonElem.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const oldText = inputElem.value;
  return inputElem.value = oldText === "ON" ? "OFF" : "ON";
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="OFF" readonly/>
  <button type="button">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to get the parent `div` and then use `querySelector` to get the child you want.

```js
const containerElem = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const buttonElem = containerElem.querySelector('button');
const inputElem = containerElem.querySelector('input');

buttonElem.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const oldText = inputElem.value;
  inputElem.value = oldText === "ON" ? "OFF" : "ON";
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" value="OFF" readonly/>
    <button type="button">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

const buttonElem = document.querySelector('#wrapper button');
const inputElem = document.querySelector('#wrapper input');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).